# c: reading negative numbers with scanf()

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I'm trying to read a list of input integers with scanf() separated by spaces into an array, but it breaks every time there's a negative number passed. How do I get it to read negative numbers as well?

```
for (int i = 0; scanf("%u", &val)==1; i++)
```

stdin:

```
1 2 -4 5
```

It will only put 1 and 2 into the array and then stop reading the rest of the numbers (I think because of the '-'?). How would I fix this?

Comment: Hint: What does the U in `%u` stand for?

Comment: Perhaps read the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and get the right format

Comment: The format specifier `%u` is for `unsigned`, so how do you expect to read signed numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `%d` specifier instead of `%u`, %u expects unsigned values only.

Comment: Make sure `val` is declared as a plain `int` as well; if you try to read a negative value into an `unsigned` object, you're not going to get what you expect.